# Need help extracting a string from a full JSON Array/Object

Tags: java, android, json

With  the below JSON output from an API I am accessing, how do I access the long city name "Southwest Portland"? It is nested so deep in objects and arrays that I am having trouble.

JSON:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "3229-3353",
               "short_name" : "3229-3353",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Southwest Dolph Court",
               "short_name" : "SW Dolph Ct",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Southwest Portland",
               "short_name" : "Southwest Portland",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Portland",
               "short_name" : "Portland",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Multnomah County",
               "short_name" : "Multnomah County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Oregon",
               "short_name" : "OR",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "97219",
               "short_name" : "97219",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
```

Here is one of my 15+ attempts of coding it below. Each time, I get something different. I'm very close, I just can't quite figure out how to pull out ONLY the neighborhood name as every address component has long_name and short_name in their title. Thank you for your help!

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    try {

        String message = "";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String JSONresults = jsonObject.getString("results");
        Log.i("JSON content", JSONresults);
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONresults);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            String neighborhoodLong = "";
            String neighborhoodShort = "";
            neighborhoodLong = jsonPart.getString("long_name");
            neighborhoodShort = jsonPart.getString("short_name");

            if (neighborhoodLong != "" && neighborhoodShort != "") {
                message += neighborhoodLong + ": " + neighborhoodShort;
            }
        }

        if (message != "") {

            Log.i("neigh", message);
            //insert succesful code here
        } else {
            //unsuccesful code goes here
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
            //error code here
    }



}
```

Comment: Use `.equals(Object)` to compare strings

Comment: This would work, but the neighborhood changes and I don't always know what it is. Essentially I put in the coordinates and Google's API tells me the neighborhood name. I'm trying to access the neighborhood name so I can display it in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I have well commented the code so that you understand.

```
try
            {
                    //This is the whole thing
                    JSONObject Jresult = new JSONObject(result);
                    //Now we take the JSONarray results
                    JSONArray Results = Jresult.getJSONArray("results");
                    //IMPORTANT
                    //Now we have to take the object in the array.  
                  //Since there is only 1 obj. You dont need a for loop
                    JSONObject ResObj = Results.getJSONObject(1);
                //Now we get the array address_components
                    JSONArray addressComps = ResObj.getJSONArray("address_components");
                  //Time to get the obj we want from the array
                    //Since u mentioned only thst one name and provided the result
                    //I knew the number in the array. In this case 3.
                    JSONObject needed = addressComps.getJSONObject(3);
                    //Now we get the required string
                    String longName = needed.getString("long_name");
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {}
```

Some important things to note. 
I didn't use a for loop because we knew the position of the object in the array. But if your dealing with it in another situation you can use the for loop. You already know it.

Also I may have got the string names of the json stuff wrong. You know, the identifying name. So just double check that in case. I hope this helps you!

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is a much easier way to do it. I have tested with some other locales and it is always the 3rd array item, so this answer will definitely work. Thank you for documenting your code, very easy to follow along and understand!

Comment: Thanks. Let me if it did work. Also if you want add a log in all of these exceptions when dealing with JSON cause it doesn't crash you but simply does nothing. Hope that helps too

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of arrays . But you are using only 1 `for loop` which is not sufficient.
You need to get inside the first array and iterate over another array -

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

               JSONArray internalArray = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("address_components");
                for (int index = 0; index < internalArray.length(); index++) {
                    String neighborhoodLong = "";
                    String neighborhoodShort = "";
                    JSONObject jsonPart = internalArray.getJSONObject(index);
                     JSONArray typeArray = jsonPart.getJSONArray("types");
            for(int counter =0 ; counter< typeArray.length(); counter++){
                if(typeArray.getString(counter).equalsIgnoreCase("neighborhood")){
                    neighborhoodLong = jsonPart.getString("long_name");
                    neighborhoodShort = jsonPart.getString("short_name");

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(neighborhoodLong) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(neighborhoodShort)) {
                        message += neighborhoodLong + ": " + neighborhoodShort;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
                }
             if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {

            Log.i("neigh", message);
            //insert succesful code here
        } else {
            //unsuccesful code goes here
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
            //error code here
    }
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Edited the answer to take care of only "neighborhood"

Comment: Shookran! That's why I couldn't figure it out, I didn't think to do another array. I'm glad I was close. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @user3552105 Did it work? But isn't there an object inside the first array which contains the second array as I have pointed out in my answer?

Comment: Correct. I was able to add in a second array and iterate through that to get my neighborhood name!

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE Your answer is very particular and I'm afraid that it will broke if there is a change in json as you are using fixed index(error prone).  I won't recommend using this approach.

Comment: Yes. I also said that if he was in a different situation use the for loop. However if in a situation like this where it is constant for loop is not required. So no need of a loop. Make it simple. In this condition a for loop Is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Use Androids [TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), which checks if a String is null or empty.

Try to replace:

```
if (neighborhoodLong != "" && neighborhoodShort != "") {
   message += neighborhoodLong + ": " + neighborhoodShort;
}
if (message != "") { 
   ... 
}
```

With:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(neighborhoodLong) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(neighborhoodShort)) {
    message += neighborhoodLong + ": " + neighborhoodShort;
}
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
   ...
}
```

Also it seems you are not parsing correctly.
"address_components" is a json array, so you have two arrays here. In your for loop try:

```
JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray address_components = jsonPart.getJsonArray("address_components");
```

Hope that helps!